# Error messege at the time of wordpress theme uploading

Tags: wordpress-theming

Hey there I am trying to install a **wordpress theme** localy on my xampp server. At the time of doing this I got this **error messege**.

**Warning**: POST Content-Length of 14409615 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Are you sure you want to do this?

**Please provide me sufficient solution of this problem(error messege).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your php.ini file to allow a larger file upload size:

See here:
[PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

You can create a phpinfo page to find the php.ini file that is loaded:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

> Please provide me sufficient solution of this problem(error messege).

I don't use xampp, so you might have to actually read the docs yourself to find where the php.ini is, but it shouldn't be too hard.